# How can I insert a link on a div in HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, href

I am not so into HTML and I have the following problem.

I have this external div:

```
<div data-wow-delay="0.25s" class="clearfix service-list odd wow fadeInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.25s; animation-name: fadeInLeft;">
    <div class="service-image">
        <img alt="test 1" src="http://localhost/onyx/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/images/no-image.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="service-detail">
        <h3>test 1</h3>
        <div class="service-content">
            <p>https://it.wikipedia.or /wiki/Pagina_principale</p>
            <p>and</p>
            <p>https://www.google.it/</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now I want add a link to the external div. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: wrap it in an anchor tag?

Comment: What are you exactly tryin to do?? oO not clear... an example? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please @AndreaNobili make a fiddle. I suppose that when you say "external div" you have a div that you're filling with external content, like an ajax call or something. Then, when document "loaded" / "ready" you have to insert a new "link" in the div filled by external data? Not sure I understand what you're asking... give more details please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/emt34tu2/).

1. obtain the `div` by `document.getElementById()` method.
2. Set value to its `innerHTML`.

Here is the snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("external").innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
```

```html
<div id="external" data-wow-delay="0.25s" class="clearfix service-list odd wow fadeInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.25s; animation-name: fadeInLeft;">
  <div class="service-image">
    <img alt="test 1" src="http://localhost/onyx/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/images/no-image.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="service-detail">
    <h3>test 1</h3>
    <div class="service-content">
      <p>https://it.wikipedia.or /wiki/Pagina_principale</p>
      <p>and</p>
      <p>https://www.google.it/</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I do it without using JavaScript?

Comment: If thats your question, then you should probably google "link in html"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`a`** element and give him atrribute **`display:block`**.

```css
a{
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#"> MY BLOCK LINK </a>
```